# Laravel routes wont work after cache:clear

Tags: php, laravel

I ran the command `cache:clear` in Laravel and now the routes will not work. Also when I try to run `route:list` a problem appears

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException .
```

Are there any commands i need to run after `cache:clear`

Comment: Try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Welcome to SO ... can you follow the stack trace to find the issue? should have more information than just the name of the exception ... also why were you running the `cache:clear` command?

Comment: Try `php artisan optimize:clear`